# Combining CONCAT, DATEDIF, and nested IF -getting #VALUE! error

Tags: excel

Trying to fill an investment field with Short/Long Term & Capital Gain/Loss. Ending values should be one of the following - STCG, STCL, LTCG, LTCL. (I tried to cut/paste an excel image but it's icky, sorry)

[Mini Spreadsheet - Date Acquired (H62), G/L per share (J62), Position (result)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1QcO.png)

For some investments, the date acquired is Var (for various purchases) or blank (for cash). If it is "Var", the function should return "LT" and skip the DATEDIF function. If the date is blank, the function should be skipped entirely and return blank as there is neither gain nor loss.

=IF($H62="","",CONCAT(IF(OR($H62="Var", DATEDIF($H62,TODAY(),"d")<365),"ST","LT"),IF($J62<0,"CL","CG")))

My original function worked well, except when the Date Acquired field (H62) had "Var", I got a #VALUE! error. I tried to do this with nested IFs and with IFS function, but couldn't get it to work (Problem with this formula error): =IF(H61="","",CONCAT(IF($H61="Var", "LT",IF(DATEDIF($H61,TODAY(),"d")<365),"ST","LT")),IF(J61<0,"CL","CG")))

The logic should be: If date="" then "" else concat LT/ST test and CL/CG test
LT/ST test: If date="Var" then "LT" else if date days before today < 365,"ST" else "LT"
CL/CG test: If gain per share <0 "CL" else "CG" (working)

Please help! I could add a hidden column (I'd rather not) or do the whole thing with nested IFs or IFS but I'd have to repeat arguments and that's sloppy & asking for trouble.

Comment: if you use the 'Evaluate Formula' under the Formulas menu item, you'll be able to see where your formula is breaking.  Also, beak down your formulas in to multiple formulas to get them working AND THEN try and combine them in an IF statement.  That way it will be much easier to debug.

Comment: `OR($H62="Var", DATEDIF($H62,TODAY(),"d")<365)` throws an error on `DATEDIF($H62,TODAY(),"d")` because `$H62` is not a date.  You should do: `IFERROR(DATEDIF($H62,TODAY(),"d"),999)`

Comment: @sous2817 Thanks - I will try the Evaluate Formula (forgot about that!). I did build the formula from the inside out, like I learned to code a long time ago! The DATEDIF, OR, second IF and CONCAT work.... it's just something when I added the IF "Var" piece, which is bizarre given it's the most basic function there. I'll post an update if I solve it - if anyone else can write the fixed function, or come up with a better solution, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: @ScottCraner - you stated "because $H62 is not a date. You should do: IFERROR(DATEDIF($H62,TODAY(),"d"),999)". H62 is a date and formatted as such. Plus when I was building the function, the DATEDIF worked on its own. That said, IFERROR is a new function to me, and I will definitely try that - it's exactly what I'm trying to do! Thanks -

Comment: When H62 = `Var` it is a string and not a date.  DATEDIF cannot handle a string in its criteria.  It will error if it is a string.

Comment: @ScottCraner I misunderstood your original post. When I error checked, that's what popped up. I had thought that the OR would back me out of the DATEDIF. When I realized that wasn't happening, that's when I tried the nested IFs to do what it seems IFERROR does. I'm trying it now, fingers crossed! Thanks

Comment: FIXED IT! =IF($H2="","",CONCAT(IF($H2="Var","LT",IF(DATEDIF($H2,TODAY(),"d")<365,"ST","LT")),IF($J2<0,"CL","CG"))). Thanks for all of the advice. Although I'd started off right with nailing the DATEDIF first, I'd added so much that I had added it in the wrong order. OR really wasn't the right function here since I needed to return "" if date was null and "LT" if date was "Var". Nesting the IFs instead of trying to do this with the IFS function and other nutty things was the key - working from the inside out. TYTYTY!!